# How to get data of html table with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to get some td data from dynamic table with selenium and push them in array. 
I tried to use:

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("row_data")
```

and get the html then find td but the list element can't get attribute innerHTML ...

```
<tr class="row_data text-silver">
                <td class="link">
                        <a href="/Account/UserCompleteRegister" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="ویرایش" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btnEditUser">
                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                        </a> 
مرضیه<input type="hidden" value="1332162477" class="userId">
                </td>
<td class="text-right">
ایرج ساعی 

</td>
<td class="text-right">
6180033005  

</td>
<td class="text-right">


</td>
<td class="text-right">
25 سال و 2 روز    

</td>
<td class="text-right">

<span class="GenderText">زن</span>


</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate through table rows and print column text with Python Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812537/iterate-through-table-rows-and-print-column-text-with-python-selenium)

Comment: try ```driver.find_elements_by_class_name("row_data.text-silver")```, space become dot. BTW for web scrapping tables i would recommend using ```pandas.read_html```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of more information with respect to which data you are exactly looking for would have helped us to construct the answer in a canonical way. However as the *class* attribute of the `<tr>` node contains **row_data** and **text-silver** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr.row_data.text-silver))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='row_data text-silver']"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If its single table on your page and  you want to use xpath then please refer below solution :

```
1.  //table//td[*]      
2.  //table//tr//td[*]
```

or else provide specific table id to handle your tabel