# Scraping Yahoo Finance stock earnings release dates with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape all company info under "Symbol", "Name", and "Earnings Call Time" from the following page: https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/earnings

I would also like selenium to go to the very next earnings date available and grab the same info as above. For example, today is November 18, so I would like to grab the same info for November 19.

I have tried several ways of doing this with selenium but cannot.

Thanks for any of your help!

Comment: Please edit the code you already tried.

Comment: I'm completely stuck, I tried just grabbing the url for each stock shown, but couldn't even do that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters the URL takes date parameters:

```
https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/earnings?day=2020-11-19
```

So you need to construct that url as such:

```
import datetime
tomorrow = (datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).isoformat() #get tomorrow in iso format as needed
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/earnings?day="+tomorrow
print ("url: " + url)
```

then you need to grab the elements you need to get data. For example:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='cal-res-table']//table")
```

From there, see working with tables in selenium here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32096039/1387701 and here: https://www.techbeamers.com/handling-html-tables-selenium-webdriver/

But you'll want to use find_elements to find the rows, and then select the td's you need from there.